# Converting JSON string to Object where a field can have two different structures

Tags: java, json, jackson

I need to use the Jackson library to parse a JSON object with a particular field `"baz"` that has object value with two kind of structures. Either I fall in this case:

```
{
  "foo": "...",
  "bar": "...",
  "baz": {
    "bazAttribute1": "...",
    "bazAttribute2": "...",
    "bazAttribute3": "..."
  }
}
```

or I fall in this other case:

```
{
  "foo": "...",
  "bar": "...",
  "baz": {
    "bazAltAttribute1": "...",
    "bazAltAttribute2": "...",
  }
}
```

Clearly the `baz` sub-object has either one structure (in the example, three attributes) or the other (two attributes with totally different names).

The way I use Jackson throughout the project is with automatic marshalling to classes, so I typically would call:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
mapper.readValue(myJsonString, FooBarBaz.class)
```

How could I design the FooBarBaz class representing the root object where there exist this twofold kind of structure?

I was thinking of using generics for this, or maybe I could make the two sub-objects implement one common interface, and use that interface in `FooBarBaz` to describe `baz`?

I am a little confused on what approach to take to make this not extremely convoluted.

Comment: If  you have two different objects why they have the same name? Else, you can add all atrtibutes from both in the same and parse it, other values will be null

Answer (score 0):

Try this. If your JSON string will not contain all of these variables, the others will be null.

```
class FooBarBaz {
    private String foo;
    private String bar;
    private Baz baz;

    //Getter  & Setter methods
}

class Baz {
    private String bazAttribute1;
    private String bazAttribute2;
    private String bazAttribute3;
}
```